# after recording using fiddler can we check whether the post parameters of a request are encoded or not

Tags: jmeter, fiddler, jmeter-3.2

My requirement is to know whether the post parameter in a request that is recorded in fiddler is encoded or not so that i can accordingly use it in Jmeter.

I tried recording a scenario in fiddler and i am able to find the post parameters for the requests sent, but I am not able to find whether a post parameter is encoded when request is sent to the server or not.

For example:
Consider the below is my post data of my request captured which has three parameters with respective values(name1,name2,name3 and value1, value2, value3 respectively)

[image]

Suppose i capture the same request using Jmeter, we will easily know whether the post parameter is encoded or not as the encode? column will be checked in case of encoding or uncecked if not encoded.

Similarly can we find whether a post parameter is encoded in fiddler, Can anyone help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the **TextView** tab in fiddler which will show you if the parameters are encoded or not, and then apply the same thing to your Jmeter script.

If you cant find that in the **TextView** tab then check the **Raw** tab which will show the full request you sent and check there if the parameters were encoded or not.